# PHP string to hex

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I have a string like that:

```
[0-9A-Za-z\+/=]*
```

How can I converted in the following form:

```
"\133\x30\55\x39\101\x2d\132\x61\55\x7a\134\x2b\57\x3d\135\x2a"
```

Is there any function for that ?

Comment: What's your schizophrenic rule for deciding whether you want the hex form or the decimal form?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function strtohex($string)
{
  $string = str_split($string);
  foreach($string as &$char)
    $char = "\x".dechex(ord($char));
  return implode('',$string);
}

print strtohex("[0-9A-Za-z\+/=]*");
```

The above code will give you

```
\x5b\x30\x2d\x39\x41\x2d\x5a\x61\x2d\x7a\x5c\x2b\x2f\x3d\x5d\x2a
```

I'm aware that it doesn't look like the output you expect, but that doesn't seem to be string to hex at all.

Comment: Cool ! Thanks ! :) I will mark your answer as answer after the 5 minutes limitation :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform such a string obfuscation, then use something like @Kristians approach. And you can alternate between the two encoding methods with e.g.:

```
 $char = (++$i%2) ? "\x".dechex(ord($char)) : "\\".decoct(ord($char));
```