# How to convert a variable to hex

Tags: php

I have a variable `$foreground = 'FF03FF'` and I want to convert that variable to `$foreground = 0xFF03FF`. How do i can convert it using php? Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537895/php-string-to-hex

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hexdec(..)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) function

```
echo hexdec('FF03FF');
```

Output: 16712703 (in hex: 0xFF03FF)